# Parsing token in HTTP Response body using C#

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I'm sending an HTTP POST request to google Client login and I'm getting this in respons:

```
SID=DQAAAGgA...7Zg8CTN
LSID=DQAAAGsA...lk8BBbG
Auth=DQAAAGgA...dk3fA5N
```

I used the below code to read the response:

```
Trace.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

Now in this response i want to use only the value of Auth token.
Can any one please help me on how to extract only that value from the response.
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick answer,
what you need to write could be something similar to this piece of code:

```
String.Split("\n").Where(l=>l.Contains("=")).Select(l=l.Split("=")).Where(li=>li.Length==2).Where(li=>li[0].ToLower()=="auth").Select(li=>li[1]).SingleOrDefault();
```